# How can I get my schema(from Azure Schema Registry) through Postman?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am trying to get the schema from Azure Schema Registry.
Is there any possibility to communicate with Schema Registry through REST API?

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the schema from the schema group in one event hub namespace, please refer to the following steps

1. Create a service principal and assign Azure RABC role `Schema Registry Reader` to the sp. For more details, please refer to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/schema-registry-overview#azure-role-based-access-control)

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role "Schema Registry Reader"  --scope <the scope according to your need>
```

2. Get token

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tennat id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=
&client_secret=
&scope=https://eventhubs.azure.net/.default
```

3. Call API

a. list schema group

```
https://<namespace name>.servicebus.windows.net/$schemagroups?api-version=2020-09-01-preview

Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

[image]

b. list schemas in one group

```
https://<namespace name>.servicebus.windows.net/$schemagroups/<group name>/schemas?api-version=2020-09-01-preview

Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

[image]

c. get one schema

```
https://<namespace name>.servicebus.windows.net/$schemagroups/<group name>/schemas/<>?api-version=2020-09-01-preview

Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is also a swagger documentation for the API: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/df4905ef3b9c864aa049f07d24d606859a657699/sdk/schemaregistry/Azure.Data.SchemaRegistry/src/schemaregistry.json

Comment: Seems like this ability has been removed in the newer versions of the REST API. I can retrieve the schema group, but appending /schemas to the path gives the following error:
```Resource Provider does not support any route matching the request URI. If this is a request for an entity with multi-segment names, encode '/' with '~' in the entity name."
```
Any ideas how to retrieve a schema using an http client these days?